Can not call method from inside ClassInitialize MSTest
I have a MS test class and I am trying to call a login interface in the [ClassInitialize] attribute of my test class. However I keep on getting the below error when I run the test case:

Class Initialization method TestAutomation.Organisation2.OneTimeSetUp threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

Stack Trace: 
ILoginManager2.UILogin(IWebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) line 20
Organisation2.OneTimeSetUp(TestContext context) line 30
RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

This is my base class:
namespace TestAutomation.TestBase
{
    public class TestBaseClass
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver;
        public static WebDriverWait wait;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void DriverSetUp()
        {
          //  IWebDriver driver;
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        } //DriverSetUp

        }
    }

Following is my Test Class:
using TestAutomation.TestBase;
namespace TestAutomation
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class Organisation2: TestBaseClass
    {

        [ClassInitialize()]
        public static void OneTimeSetUp(TestContext context)
        {
            ILoginManager2.UILogin(driver, wait); //driver and wait inherited from TestBaseClass
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public  void Login()
        {
        //code
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        public void CreateOrg()
        {
        //code
    }

Following is the interface method I am trying to call from inside the ClassInitialize attribute in the above test class:
namespace SAMSAutomation
{
    public interface ILoginManager2
    {

       public static void UILogin(IWebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait)
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com");

            IWebElement tbUserName = driver.FindElement(By.Name("SWEUserName"));
            IWebElement tbPassword = driver.FindElement(By.Name("SWEPassword"));
            IWebElement bLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("s_swepi_22"));

            tbUserName.SendKeys("User");
            tbPassword.SendKeys("Password");

            bLogin.Click();

            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.LinkText("Home")));

        }
    }
}

I am new to both Selenium and C#.
Any feedback would be much appreciated.
When I try to move this code under [TestInitilaize] it works fine. However I do not want that as it would launch the browser and do login before each and every test method.

Who initialises driver and wait?

Best practice is to have a fresh browser for each test. That way you get the cleanest run possible with no interference by other tests. If you run all tests in a single browser, later tests are more likely to cause issues with each other. Having one browser per test also gives you the ability to run all tests in parallel for maximum speed.

Thanks very much or the feedback. I will incorporate these changes in my test. Regarding the LoginManager() method not getting invoked from the [ClassInitialise] , do you have any idea ?

Where are the driver and wait fields being initialized? Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code, which in your case likely needs the base class code.

I have now updated the above code with the base class. If you could please provide some feedback as to why I still keep on getting this error, it would be great.
